# This Bayesian classifer gem gives the following error: can't add a new key into hash during iteration - how can I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to use the bayes_motel gem to analyse some data. I think there's an incompatibility between my version of ruby and the gem's creation of hashes:

```
 ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bayes_motel-0.1.0/lib/bayes_motel/corpus.rb:89:in `[]=': can't add a new key into hash during iteration (RuntimeError)
```

This is the relevant code in the gem:

```
  def clean(hash, k, v)
    case v
    when Hash
      v.each_pair do |key, value|
        clean(v, key, value)
      end
      if v.empty?
        hash.delete(k)
      elsif v.size == 1 and v['other']
        hash.delete(k)
      end
    else
      if v < (@total_count * 0.03).floor
        hash['other'] ||= 0
        hash['other'] += v
        hash.delete(k)
      end
    end
 end
```

I have been following this tutorial:

http://www.mikeperham.com/2010/04/28/bayes_motel-bayesian-classification-for-ruby/

And the demo on the gem:

https://github.com/mperham/bayes_motel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Change this:

```
v.each_pair do |key, value|
```

..to this:

```
v.to_a.each do |key, value|
```

Would be best to rerun the test cases to make sure though.

Comment: Awesome thanks. There were several instances of the each_pair method. Has that been deprecated?

Comment: @burtonic - No it hasn't been deprecated, but in ruby 1.9 hash iteration was changed so that modifying the hash while iterating results in a runtime error. In 1.8 you could do it, but in 1.9 you can't. It's a protection from unexpected side effects from modifying while iterating.